# clicking on custom checkbox does not run the associated onClick function

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick

I'm trying to use Ryan Fait's custom checkboxes.  These are much more readable than the standard checkboxes, but clicking on them does not run the associated `onClick` functions.  Any advice will be appreciated.  The relevant portion of my code follows:

```
<p style="font-family:arial; font-size:large">

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="level-0" type="radio" value="0"
onClick="count();"> &nbsp;0 (ages 5-7)&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="level-1" type="radio" value="1"
onClick="count();" checked>&nbsp;1 (beginner)&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="level-2" type="radio" value="2"
onClick="count();" checked>&nbsp;2 (easy)&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="level-3" type="radio" value="3"
onClick="count();" checked>&nbsp;3 (intermediate)&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="level-4" type="radio" value="4"
onClick="count();"> &nbsp;4 (challenging)&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="level-5" type="radio" value="5"
onClick="count();"> &nbsp;5 (hard)&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="level-all" type="radio" value="6"
onClick="all_levels();"> &nbsp;All&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input id="available" type="button" style="background-color:white; border:2px;
font-family:arial; font-size:large" value="??"> </p> <br>
```

Comment: The "relevant" portion should also include the associated JavaScript, which would give some way of testing your code.

Comment: is it supposed to have two values for the 'type' attribute on each input?

Comment: It should **not** have two values for "type". I pasted the above, and my browser made them checkboxes, presumably because that's the first `type` mentioned.

Comment: Good point about the two values for "type".  Thanks!

Comment: The released version of the page in question is at the following URL: http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/hangman.html  The beta version, in which I'm attempting to use the custom checkboxes, it at http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/hangman.new.html

Answer (score 0):

From [Styling Checkboxes and Radio Buttons With CSS and JavaScript](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) on Ryan Fait's site:

> **How does it work?**
>
> In a nutshell, the JavaScript looks for every form element with
>   class="styled" on it; hides the real form element; sticks a span tag
>   with a CSS class on it next to the element; and, finally, mouse events
>   are added to the span that handles the visual stages form inputs go
>   through when they are clicked.

Your inline `onClick` handlers are not firing because your checkboxes aren't actually being clicked. Ryan explicitly says that it "hides the real form element; sticks a span tag with a CSS class" ... so you are actually clicking on the `<span>` that Ryan's code inserted; the real checkbox is hidden.

Later in the article, Ryan says outright:

> **onChange and other JavaScript events**
>
> This script utilizes JavaScript's onChange and other events. Because
>   these events can only be used once, if you want to add more functions
>   to an event, **you will need to call them from inside my script.**

### You will need to call them from inside my script

Take your `onClick=` out of the `<input>` tags; add your code to his code -- you'll have to figure out which bit of your code to call from his code, since I see you're doing different things from your onClicks.

You should also take your `style="..."` out of your tags and use a stylesheet, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I'm starting to have an inkling of what's going on here, but am still confused.  I'm currently calling two different functions via onClick.  It seems as though there must be some property of the <input> tag that identifies the function to be called, so I don't see how I can remove this.

Comment: There is *not* a property of the input tag to identify the function to be called. Specifying `onclick="someJavascript"` overwrites any existing click handler; in fact specifying handlers inline like that is generally discouraged. The best method is *attaching* a handler in a completely separate `.js` file. jQuery is great for that because it will add a handler along with any exising handler. With plain javascript (no jQuery, or Dojo, or Prototype) you must check if there's an existing handler and call it from your handler. Google for `chaining event handlers javascript` for plain .js tips.